# How to solve "fetch schema failed" problem in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone encountered this problem? I can't query out the data I need in Apache IoTDB, and error reported: `executeStatement failed. Fetch Schema failed.` My IoTDB version is 1.0.1. What should I do now to return to normal operating status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade Apache IoTDB to Version 1.1.0, then this bug will be solved. For updating process, you can download the new version, stop your data writing, replace the lib package in IoTDB, and then continue your data writing. No data will be missed in this way.